# Windows HPC Server 08 suitability for Matlabs

Tags: windows-server-2008, hpc

I want to setup another Hyper-V VM for installing Matlabs/doing some compute-intensive programming using C.

I keep thinking that Windows Server HPC 2008 is designed for this sort of work. Would I be on the right track to setup a single VM with this OS and install this software? Or is HPC more for grid/distributed computing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure Windows HPC will work fine for your proposed usage, but yes, it is focused on traditional HPC/Beowulf style clusters. If you're just going to be developing code/running Matlab, there's probably no advantage to using Windows Server HPC until it comes time to deploy your code on a cluster or if you need to develop/test MPI stuff.

The biggest differences are that Windows Server HPC includes things like Microsoft's MPI stack and an HPC optimized network stack, along with things like a job scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for HPC + MATLAB Distributed Computing Server : 
http://www.mathworks.com/products/distriben/